# Difference between .NET thread API & OpenMP?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

.NET thread API and OpenMP can be used in shared memory programming. What is the difference in these approaches?

Comment: Hard to guess what "thread API" might mean.  But OpenMP is roughly similar to .NET's TPL (Task Parallel Library).  Using threading without ever using the word "thread" explicitly, leaving that up to the Smart People.